# Twitter API v2のBatch compliance(Compliance Firehose API)でGoogle API Storageにアップロードする方法がわからない

Tags: swift, twitter

[Twitter Batch compliance(Compliance Firehose API)](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/compliance/batch-compliance/introduction)をやろうとしているのですが、手順１でJobの作成ができ、upload_urlを取得まではできたのですが、その次の手順2である`ファイルのアップロード`の方法がわかりません。

ファイルの中身は`ツイートID` or `ユーザーID`の羅列が必要そうなのですが、そのファイル(データ)をupload_urlにアップロードする方法がわかりません。

どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/twttr-tweet-compliance/1579097950700961793/submission/1468034183536984067_1579097950700961793?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=complianceapi-public-svc-acct%40twttr-compliance-public-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20221009%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20221009T131424Z&X-Goog-Expires=900&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost&X-Goog-Signature=2703915919f8aff425e84f790ad114b81")!
        
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
var request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
let tweetIDs = ["1577730467436138524", "1565318587736285184", "1565318587736285184", "1564694842311049217"]
request.httpBody = tweetIDs.joined(separator: "\n").data(using: .utf8)!
    
let (responseData, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

print(String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>
GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
20221009T131424Z
20221009/auto/storage/goog4_request
5c45ee0335cfb583f650af1d68f9fb10b2f72e34aed04a5ca8ad22942a537020
</StringToSign>
<CanonicalRequest>
POST
/twttr-tweet-compliance/1579097950700961793/submission/1468034183536984067_1579097950700961793
X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&amp;X-Goog-Credential=complianceapi-public-svc-acct%40twttr-compliance-public-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20221009%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&amp;X-Goog-Date=20221009T131424Z&amp;X-Goog-Expires=900&amp;X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
host:storage.googleapis.com

content-type;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
</CanonicalRequest>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"POST"ではなく"PUT"でした